# How can I use "to_xs" in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know this is in the `builder` gem. So I put it in my Gemfile. Then I `bundle install`.

Running in the console, I type:

```
x = "akwf"
```

then:

```
x.to_xs
```

and am rewarded with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_xs' for "akwf":String
```

When I try `require 'builder'` and `require 'builder/xchar'` I am met with `false`.

What basic item am I missing in order for me to perform this basic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that Rails includes `builder` already, so no need to add it to the `Gemfile`.

Second, a false return value when requiring isn't really bad. It just means that the library has already been successfully required and didn't need to be re-required. If `require` is having trouble loading a library, it'll raise an exception, not return false.

Third, `builder/xchar.rb` specifies that, if `String#encode` is defined, then it skips the old `String#to_xs` definition and instead defines `Builder::XChar.encode(string)`, which seems to serve the same purpose. Try requiring `builder/xchar` and giving that a shot.